# Node.js Nodemailer doesn't send the email, i dont get any errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nodemailer

I just trying to set up nodemailer contact form. ITs working well, i get status: 200, but i dont recieve email from the form. I tryed with other email, its still dont work. Thank you very much for your help.
Here is my Server.js code (i deleted the irrelevant codes) :)

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))


app.post('/contact',(req,response)=>{
const output=`
  <p>You have a new contact request</p>
  <img class="email" src="cid:email" alt="email-image">
  <h3>Contact details</h3>
  <ul>
  <li>FirstName: ${req.body.name}</li>
  <li>TelNum: ${req.body.telephone}</li>
  <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
  <li>Message: ${req.body.message}</li>
  </ul>`
const smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
    name: 'cwebdesignmail',
    host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
    port: 587,    
    secure: true,
    security:STARTTLS,
  auth:{ 
  user:process.env.EMAIL,
  pass:process.env.PASS,
  }})
const mailOpts = {
  from:process.env.EMAIL,
  to:process.env.EMAIL,
  subject:'New message from Nodemailer-contact-form',
  html:output,
  attachments: [{
  filename: 'email.jpg',
  path:__dirname + '/public/images/logo.png',cid: 'email' //same cid value as in the html img src
  }]}
smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts,(error,res)=>{
   if(error){
   console.log(error);
   }
   else{
    console.log("Message sent: " + res.message);
    response.status(200).send(200)
    }
  //smtpTrans.close();
   })
})
```

app.js:

```
const form = document.getElementById('contact-form')
const formEvent = form.addEventListener("submit",(event)=>{
  event.preventDefault()
  const name = form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
  const email = form.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].value
  const telephone = form.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value
  const message = form.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value
  sendEmail(name,email,telephone,message)
})

function sendEmail(name, email,telephone, message) {
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      telephone:telephone,
      message: message
    })
    };
  return fetch("/contact", options)
    .then(res =>{
      if(res.status === 200){
        Swal.fire({
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Your message has been sent Successfully!',
        })
        form.reset()
      }else{
        Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Error, please try agian!',
        })
        }
      })
  }
```

If someone can answer this, i would be very grateful.

Comment: Why do you post the entire code of your application? Please short the code to the relevant parts. Nobody will go through all these lines.

Comment: Ty, i deleted it.

Comment: You define a `const body` in your `app.js`, but don't use it at all. Shouldn't you include that in the POST request?

Comment: Ty for the answer, i use in server.js post output... Or what u mean? :)